# AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, amazon-web-services

Solution explorer in VS 2010 SP1 crash after installing AWS Toolkit for VS2010:

An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged by running the application with the `/log` parameter on the command line, which stores results in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml`.

Exception details:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?